# Difference between tf.layers.dense and tf.nn.xw_plus_b

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

What is the difference between `tf.layers.dense` and `tf.nn.xw_plus_b` in `TF`? 
What is the default activation used in `tf.layers.dense` when "activation" argument is passed as `None`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tf.nn.xw_plus_b` is a low-level operation that only computes `x*W+b` and requires existing variables.

`tf.layers.dense` is a high-level "layer" that creates variables, apply activation can set constrains and apply regularization.

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) default activation is linear (no activation).

> **activation**: Activation function (callable). Set it to None to maintain
>   a linear activation.

**Update**

In Tensorflow 1.12 `Dense` layer inherits  `keras.layers.Dense` ([code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L32)):

```py
@tf_export('layers.Dense')
class Dense(keras_layers.Dense, base.Layer):
```

Keras implementation of this layer does the following ([code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L958)):

```py
  def call(self, inputs):
    inputs = ops.convert_to_tensor(inputs, dtype=self.dtype)
    rank = common_shapes.rank(inputs)
    if rank > 2:
      # Broadcasting is required for the inputs.
      outputs = standard_ops.tensordot(inputs, self.kernel, [[rank - 1], [0]])
      # Reshape the output back to the original ndim of the input.
      if not context.executing_eagerly():
        shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
        output_shape = shape[:-1] + [self.units]
        outputs.set_shape(output_shape)
    else:
      outputs = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(inputs, self.kernel)
    if self.use_bias:
      outputs = nn.bias_add(outputs, self.bias)
    if self.activation is not None:
      return self.activation(outputs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    return outputs
```

So it is not implemented using `tf.nn.xw_plus_b` but uses two separate operations.

To answer your question: `Dense` layer without activation, constraints and regularization should do the same as `tf.nn.xw_plus_b`.

Comment: I need to replace a denser layer for my problem.Dense layer with activation as none , will it be similar to xw_plus_b(functionality wise). Is it wise to replace dense with xw_plus_b? I agree that xw_plus_b need external variables, once if all necessary variables are passed to it will it behave similar to dense without activation?